# Access not possible for my index

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I've created 2 models (`User` & `Poste`) with their controllers (`UserController` & `PosteController`) thanks to the method of creation with 'Read/Write actions and views, using Entity Framework'.

Everything goes well for the `Poste`, I can create, edit, delete...

The problem is related to the `User`. In fact, when I put `/User` in my URL to access to the index, this error appears to me :

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Nom d'objet
>   'dbo.Users' non valide.

This is `User` model code :

```
    public class User
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "Matricule :")]
        public string Matricule { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom :")]
        public string Nom_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Le {0} doit avoir au minimum {2} caractères.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Mot de passe :")]
        public string passWord { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Type :")]
        public string Type_User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "ID_UF :")]
        public string ID_UF { get; set; }
    }

    public class GammeDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is the `UserController` code :

```
    public class UserController : Controller
    {
        private GammeDBContext db = new GammeDBContext();

        //
        // GET: /User/
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Users.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Details/5
        public ViewResult Details(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /User/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /User/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(User user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // GET: /User/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(string id)
        {
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            return View(user);
        }

        //
        // POST: /User/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
        {            
            User user = db.Users.Find(id);
            db.Users.Remove(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
```

and this is what I added in my `web.config` file :

```
<add name="GammeDBContext" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SWEET-DE396641E\SQLEXPRESS;database=Flux; Integrated Security=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="GammeDBContextP" 
     connectionString="Data Source=SWEET-DE396641E\SQLEXPRESS;database=Flux; Integrated Security=true" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

PS :

- `GammeDBContext` is for the 'User'
- `GammeDBContextP` is for the 'Poste'

So is there any solution ?

Comment: Do you have the database table? Or was it updated? Also why do you need two connection strings?

Comment: The database was created automatically when i created the model (Methode Code First)
I have 2 connection strings because when I created the Model of Poste, I declared this class : public class GammeDBContext : DbContext { public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; } } but the Editor didn't accept it and showed me an error so i change it to this : public class GammeDBContextP : DbContext { public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; } }

Answer (score 0):

is your database table called 'User'? If it is, try throwing this code in with your context class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
```

This bugged the bajeezus out of me one time.

Also why do you have 2 identical connection strings?

Comment: thanks for your answer,
I don't have a Context Class because I follow the Code First Methode (that's mean i don't generate from a database).
I used 2 identicak connection strings because when I created the Model of Poste, I declared this class :
public class GammeDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
    }
but the Editor didn't accept it and showed me an error so i change it to this :
public class GammeDBContextP : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
    }